# Server-side validation to prevent illegal POST requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

For my webapp (angular + node.js), I'm implementing a gamification system where users gain points for performing actions like answering questions, watching a video, etc. Currently, I simply post to '/api/users/updatepoints' with the user's id and number of points changed to update the database.

This is of course not secure, since a user could easily do an ajax request from the console while logged in, and I was wondering how I can prevent users from illegally sending out ajax requests? What sort of server-side validation could I use to do so?

```
//front end
$http.post('/api/users/updatepoints', {
  kidId: xxx,
  pointsChanged: yyy
})

//backend
exports.updatePoints = function(req, res) {
  var kidId = req.body.kidId,
    pointsChanged = req.body.pointsChanged;

  User.findOne({_id: kidId}, function(err, user) {
    if (err) return res.send(400);
    user.points += pointsChanged;
    user.save(function(err) {
      if (err) return res.send(400);
      return res.send(200)
    });
  })
}
```

Comment: Adding points should be only in backend. ie: client answer a question then the server add the answer and also add a point

Comment: @Vinz243 Thanks for the info, but how would you prevent someone from making an illegal ajax request in that case? Suppose the user gets a point for clicking a button, and everytime he clicks a button, it sends a post request {kidId: xxx, event: 'clickButton"}, and then one checks on the backend and then increments points. However, one could easily just do $.post('/yyy', {kidId: xxx, event: 'clickButton'}) on the console repeatedly, and illegally get the points without actually clicking the button. I'm wondering how to defend against that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is "you can't".

A sufficiently determined hacker will always be able to take control of anything you are running on their computer. The only way to avoid that is to validate everything server side.

For example the only way to defeat "map hacks" in competitive online play is to never send information to the client unless that information is being displayed to the user.

If it's important, do it server side. Let the client side do its processing and validate and verify everything it sends you.

This is much too big a subject to properly discuss in a format like this though. Try doing some internet searches on preventing client hacks in games.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. I think I'll restructure some of the code to be done server side like you suggested then.